# MediaPlayer does not appear in Toolbox even when adding from COM Components.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have googled so much about this issue.  I have Visual Studio 2013. Following instructions: right click in toolbox, add mediaplayer from COM components and still this error:

Element 'MediaPlayer' is not a known element.  This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Website, or the web.config file is missing.

config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

There is no error in website, I have the latest Silverlight.  Please can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed is the System.Web.Silverlight.dll. file adding.  Instructions:

1.Right click on toolbox (anywhere)
2.Select choose item
3.When the window opens click browse and search for your dll file.